I have been trying to add react slick slider in my project but it doesn't work
Like I have done a lot of my work in this react project and I used vite to initialise it but now I need to use react slick slider and it's not working. I tried to do it without vite and it worked fine. Problem is that the component render just for a second and disappears.
I used chatGPT and all that stuff but it isn't working

need to show some code if you want any help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
